# Psycopg2 "operator does not exist: integer[] = integer" error

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

Given a table called `namespace_list` with an `INTEGER[]` column called `namespace_ids`.

I have the following query:

```
query = SELECT * FROM namespace_list WHERE namespace_ids = ANY(%s) 
and application_id=%s
```

which I am executing as:

```
cur.execute(query, data)
```

and where data is:

```
data = ([1, 2], 1)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
operator does not exist: integer[] = integer at character 50\nHINT:
No operator matches the given name and argument type(s).
You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Why is this not working? Looking at http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAG7mmoxZdRdatjWSYLBCVGJ4CPMa38ARSZByWe9xrWHKP0mB1g@mail.gmail.com, and other tutorials on Postgres Arrays, it seems that I have the correct query.

I am following what http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#adapt-list has as an example as well. Is there anything wrong with my query, or the way I am using arrays with psycopg2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the SQL expression:

```
<column> = ANY(<array>)
```

returns true if the *scalar* value in `<column>` is equal to any value in `<array>` comparing the values one by one. But your column is not a scalar value, it is an array and that's why PostgreSQL says:

```
operator does not exist: integer[] = integer
```

An operator to compare an array (left) to any integer (right) doesn't exists. To fix this you can use an intersection operator (`&&`) (if you need to match just one id from both sets) or the equality operator (`=`) if you want to match all array elements:

```
SELECT * FROM namespace_list WHERE namespace_ids && %s and application_id=%s
```

The trick here is that psycopg converts Python lists to literal arrays (`ARRAY[...]`) that you can use anywhere you would use them in standard SQL.

Comment: How come? Psycopg2 says we can do this: `ids = [10, 20, 30]
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM data WHERE id = ANY(%s);", (ids,))`.  This is exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: I need to check for exact match. When doing query `SELECT * FROM namespace_list WHERE namespace_ids = ARRAY%s and application_id=%s` with data `([1, 2], 1)`, I get: `syntax error at or near "," at character 64`. Why is it not accepting the array now?

Comment: Because it is not what you are doing. `where id = ANY(%s)` works because on the left you have a scalar and not an array. But you said that namespace_ids is ab array so (see my answer) it can't work.

Comment: If you want equality between arrays just use `=`. Remove ARRAY from the query in your comment and it should work.